AlpineJS submit a form without refreshing the page
I am working with Hyva theme with AlpineJs on Magento and using a <form> with the needed inputs to add a product to the shopping cart.
This is part of the form code:
    <form method="post"
          id="product_addtocart_form"
    >
        <input name="product" />
        <input name="selected_configurable_option"  />
        <input name="related_product" />
        <input name="item">
    </form>

And this is the button I am using to submit the form:
    <button type="submit" form="product_addtocart_form">
        Submit
    </button>

Everything works great. However, I want to add a modal that shows after a product is added to the shopping cart but as soon as the product is added the page refreshes.
I found plenty of similar topics but nothing did it for me. I have already tried using event.preventDefault() and onsubmit="return false". Both don't refresh the page but a product is not added.
I also tried adding products using an HTTP post method which partly solved the issue but when it comes to adding products with configurable options, it becomes too complicated.
Would you have any suggestions or ideas for an approach I can take to stop refreshing the page after a form is submitted?

Try following steps:
Add a @submit.prevent directive to the form to prevent the default form submission behavior.
<form method="post" id="product_addtocart_form" @submit.prevent="submitForm">
  <input name="product" x-model="product" />
  <input name="selected_configurable_option" x-model="selectedConfigurableOption" />
  <input name="related_product" x-model="relatedProduct" />
  <input name="item" x-model="item" />
  <button type="submit" form="product_addtocart_form">Submit</button>
</form>

AND
<div x-show="showModal" @click.away="showModal = false" style="display: none;">
  <div class="modal-content">
    Product successfully added to the cart!
    <button @click="showModal = false">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>

Use Fetch API for AJAX request, make an AJAX request to the server to add the product to the cart, handle the server response and display
the modal if the product is successfully added.
function addToCart() {
  return {
    product: '',
    selectedConfigurableOption: '',
    relatedProduct: '',
    item: '',
    showModal: false,
    async submitForm() {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('product', this.product);
        formData.append('selected_configurable_option', this.selectedConfigurableOption);
        formData.append('related_product', this.relatedProduct);
        formData.append('item', this.item);

        try {
            const response = await fetch('/path/to/your/add-to-cart/api', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                },
            });

            if (response.ok) {
                const data = await response.json();
                
                if (data.success) {
                    this.showModal = true;
                } else {
            
                    console.error('Error adding product to cart:', data.message);
                }
            } else {
                console.error('Network response was not ok.');
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        }
    }
  };
}

You can use <div x-data="addToCart()"> to wrap the overall modal and <form> so that the function will work.

Please have  look at markdown help

I will need to make some modifications to the code to eliminate errors that appear with it. Other than that it can get me closer to what I need and it can be used as a temporary solution until a better one is found/posted
